# SIGBART ERROR vector<list<myClass> >

Tags: c++, xcode, list, graph, vector

I cannot find the reason why my program throws a SIGBART error.

I've narrowed it down when this function is called.

```
bool Node::isEdgeConnected(Node vertex1, Node vertex2){

//I'm not sure if this is the right way to copy this vector <list>
vector<list<Node> > myEdgeList = *edgeList;//edgeList is a private data member of Node

vector<list<Node> >::iterator it;
cout << myEdgeList.size();


for (it = myEdgeList.begin(); it != myEdgeList.end(); it++) {
    list<Node> edge;
    edge = *it;
    Node placeNode = edge.front();

    cout <<placeNode.getNodeId()<<endl;
    list<Node>::iterator eIt;
    for (eIt = edge.begin(); eIt != edge.end(); eIt++) {
        Node placeNode1, placeNode2;
        placeNode1 = edge.front();
        placeNode2 = *eIt;

        cout << placeNode1.getNodeId() << " " << placeNode2.getNodeId()<<endl;
        if(placeNode1.getNodeId() == vertex1.getNodeId() &&
           placeNode2.getNodeId() == vertex2.getNodeId()){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: assert edgeList is not null, something like  `assert(edgeList!=NULL)`

Comment: Also if you can post the back trace from the debugger when compiled with high debug flags (-ggdb) and no optimisations (-O0).

Comment: Is what header file is assert declared in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your code fails in line `Node placeNode = edge.front();`, you need to check if `edge` is empty or not

```
if (edge.empty()){
   continue;
}
Node placeNode = edge.front();
```

BTW, `isEdgeConnected()` function is just to check node value inside `edgeList`, you don't need to copy all elements. if your `edgeList` is big, copy will be expensive.

For example, you could iterate `edgeList` directly, also `++iter` is more efficient than `iter++, see [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/increment-pre-post-speed.html)

```
for (vector<list<Node> >::iterator it = edgeList->begin();                                       
     it != edgeList->end(); ++it) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks that cleared the problem. Now I have to figure out how to access the data from my private vector containing lists.

Comment: please post another questions, people will answer quickly